# How To Make A Coverage Area in The Map (Like Foursquare app)?

Tags: android, google-maps, mapping

I'm still a beginner in Android and I want to make a map which is similar like this picture..

Link to this picture..

[Foursquare app](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-dl17i9myVi8/Te9HZVRwn3I/AAAAAAAAAC0/Rtq-Mygzx-w/device.png)

Based on the picture that I take from Foursquare app, I want to make coverage area that based on the radius I decide..

There's a point where it's a user current location and also a circle which covers the point (shown in blue color).

I get the idea about how to make a point (I was told that I could use Geopoint), but I still don't know how to make the coverage area like that circle that I described before..

Is it possible to do this???

Does it have any relationship with Google Maps API??

What should first I do since I'm still a beginner in Android, especially in Mapping like these???

Answer (score 0):

The coverage area circle is the accuracy of your location via the network provider , not a feature from 4Square :-).

Edit : If you want to implement it you can probably show a circular drawable where you want.

Comment: Ok, I understood... 
But, the question is it possible to make the similar thing in Android application???